# Text link won't submit form by JavaScript in Safari using name

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari, submit

I'm using Safari 5.0.3 I have a form in my html:

```
<form name="searchForm" style="margin-top:24px;">
<h4 style="float:left;margin-top:-1px;">Search</h4> 
&nbsp; <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords"></input> &nbsp; <a href="#" onClick="document.forms[0].submit(); return false">Go ></a>
</form>
```

This works fine:

```
a href="#" onClick="document.forms[0].submit(); return false"
```

but this does nothing:

```
a href="#" onClick="document.forms['searchForm'].submit(); return false"
```

I need to use the latter, because the page template is dynamic, and sometimes there will be a form in the page before this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: document.getElementById('searchForm').submit() instead.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. The Safari JavaScript debugger says "TypeError: Result of expression 'document.searchForm' [undefined] is not an object."

Comment: My apologies, should have also specified that you need to add an Id attribute to the form per Levi.

Comment: Bummer. Still no go. Debugger says "TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById('searchForm')' [null] is not an object."

Comment: id="searchForm" is the attribute you added?

Comment: Typo on my part. Initially added as "searchform." Now it works. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.searchForm.submit(); return false;">
```

If that doesn't work, Macy Abbey has a great idea of adding an id to the form and referencing it by that.