# How can I get Safari to submit a form with .submit()?

Tags: jquery, forms, safari

I have some form elements that will submit data on change with the following jQuery

```
$("#select-id").change(function() {
    $("form").submit();
});
```

However, with Safari 6.0.5, this no longer works. I've tested in Chrome and FF, both work. Normally the request is reflected in the url, like

`search?=global&sort_by=search_api_relevance&items_per_page=50`

except in the case of Safari. I've looked a bit and there are several people reporting exceptional behavior with Safari and jQuery form submissions, but I haven't found something this simple reported, yet.

Comment: submit is a pure javascript method, so you need to do `$('form').get(0).submit()`, or if there is multiple forms give this one an ID and reference it that way.

Comment: Yes, I understand this syntax; but I actually need to have the function submit ANY form in the DOM, the way Chrome and FF are interpreting the statement. The reason for this is hard to explain succinctly, and there may be a better way to construct my page. But, if I could find a way to have Safari behave the same as the others, I'd take that route.

Comment: the reason i made that comment is because jquery's function to execute `.submit()` may be doing something that safari is barking at. here is someone who faced the same problem and got it working using `document.getElementById('yourForm').submit()` syntax => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845480/text-link-wont-submit-form-by-javascript-in-safari-using-name. you can also use `document.forms[0].submit()` and it will work.

Comment: This helps, if only to know what doesn't work in my case! Anyway, I have an unusual situation, where the form markup changes in certain circumstances. In essence, the changes in one form (form-id1) are sent via another form (form-id2). I can see why Safari doesn't like this, in fact, no browser should like it. But Chrome and FF understand my intentions and Safari does not.